# Python/Experta Rule engine not running as expect

Tags: python, rule-engine, experta

I have the following code, and the Experta engine gives unexpected output: `None`. Is the `P` predicate function applied correctly?

```
from experta import Fact, KnowledgeEngine, L, AS, Rule, P, AND



class QuoteFact(Fact):
    """Info about the traffic light."""
    pass


class GoodSymbolFact(Fact):
    pass


class _RuleEngine(KnowledgeEngine):
    @Rule(
        QuoteFact(P(lambda x: float(x.price) > 1.00))
    )
    def accept(self, quote_fact):
        good_symbol_fact = GoodSymbolFact(symbol=quote_fact.symbol)
        self.declare(good_symbol_fact)


_engine = _RuleEngine()
_engine.reset()
_engine.declare(QuoteFact(price=100.00, symbol="AAPL"))

result = _engine.run()
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/nilp0inter/experta/blob/753e6490e0afd991d150f29b95b62eaa46b75d97/experta/engine.py#L130) of the `run` method you'll see that it doesn't return anything. So `result` will always be `None`. If you want to access the facts declared in your engine, you can simply loop over them:

```py
from experta import Fact, KnowledgeEngine, L, AS, Rule, P, AND

class QuoteFact(Fact):
    """Info about the traffic light."""
    pass

class GoodSymbolFact(Fact):
    pass

class _RuleEngine(KnowledgeEngine):
    @Rule(
        QuoteFact(P(lambda x: float(x.price) > 1.00))
    )
    def accept(self, quote_fact):
        good_symbol_fact = GoodSymbolFact(symbol=quote_fact.symbol)
        self.declare(good_symbol_fact)

_engine = _RuleEngine()
_engine.reset()
_engine.declare(QuoteFact(price=100.00, symbol="AAPL"))

_engine.run()
for fact in _engine.facts.items():
    print(fact)
```

Output:

```
(0, InitialFact())
(1, QuoteFact(price=100.0, symbol='AAPL'))
```

Note: alternatively, you can keep track of the added facts by letting your rules print some stuff when they run, just like in the [examples](https://github.com/nilp0inter/experta) in the README.